# Table cell automaticly changes its size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my div all time 34px somehow it changes its size every time i zoom in or zoom out on the page.
One time it is too high and one time to low. What am i doing wrong?

```
.input-group-addon.sufix {
padding: 6px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-top: 8px;
height: 34px !important;
width: 27px !important;
}
```

and some screens:

[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY9U5.png)

[Too high](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKJkN.png)

[Too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyTwn.png)

Comment: From what I can see it's a font so don't be surprised that it gets bigger when scaling.

Comment: It destroys integrity that i want to display, just doesnt look ok, is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: When you zoom in / out a page, each element on the page is changed. It cannot be blocked. Ie. maybe not so, it can be seen on mobile devices by the appropriate meta setting.

Comment: Can i change it to something else so it would not scale?

Comment: No, every page is scalable with ctrl + wheel or ctrl + +/-

Comment: I mean to maybe change something diffrent so the size will always stay 34px

Comment: You can write, the text at the top "my page looks bad when zooming in/out" so don't do it ;)

Comment: Print it out to ensure nobody's gonna zoom.